# How to use contents of a file stored in a variable, instead of creating a file with the contents in bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to convert a OpenSSL private key to OpenSSH public Key.
I am doing this using the following command.
ssh-keygen -f  -y

Now i want this to be done using a variable which contains the contents of "OpenSSL-Private-Key-File", Instead of using the "OpenSSL-Private-Key" itself. How can this be done in bash. I am trying to avoid creation of files. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
read -r -d '' VARIABLEKEY << EOM
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOM
echo "$VARIABLEKEY" | ssh-keygen -y -f /dev/stdin
```

Comment: Here documents are implemented with temporary files (although this could vary from shell to shell), so this may not work depending on the objection to creating a file.